# php array unset not working

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array called "values".  This is how `var_dump($values)` looks now.

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["content"]=> array(1) { 
            ["items"]=> array(4) { 
                [0]=> string(4) "3121" 
                [1]=> string(4) "3116" 
                [2]=> string(4) "3115" 
                [3]=> string(4) "3114" 
            } 
        } 
        ["options"]=> array(8) { 
            ["title"]=> string(7) "inherit" 
            ["size"]=> string(4) "tiny" 
            ["orderby"]=> string(4) "date" 
            ["order"]=> string(4) "desc" 
            ["filter"]=> string(8) "category" 
            ["pagination"]=> bool(false) 
            ["per_page"]=> int(12) 
            ["content"]=> array(3) { 
                [0]=> string(5) "title" 
                [1]=> string(7) "excerpt" 
                [2]=> string(4) "tags" 
            } 
        } 
        ["__version"]=> string(5) "2.3.1" 
    }
}
```

Here is the code i'm using to unset the value

```
 //before unset
    var_dump($values);

    $ID = "3121";
    foreach ($values as $value) {
                    foreach($value['content']['items'] as $key => $val) {               
                    if($val == $ID) {
                     unset($value['content']['items'][$key]);
                     }
                    }
        }

   //after unset
    var_dump($values);
```

My var_dump looks same even after unset. I think my array unset not working. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In php arrays are passed by value instead of by reference change

```
 foreach ($values as $value) {
```

to

```
 foreach ($values as &$value) {
```

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for relevant documentation.

Comment: @Giri Remember to use `unset($value)` after the for loop has ended (this will delete the REFERENCE, **NOT** the variable), or you have a useless reference lying around in your code (which essentially means that if you delete the last value, eg. by using `array.pop`, it'll stay in memory, as you're referencing it somewhere else)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't put a `$key` variable in the for loop and to change value you have to use a reference

```
foreach ($values as &$value) {
  foreach($value['content']['items'] as $key => $val) {               
      if($val == $ID) {
          unset($value['content']['items'][$key]);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, It still looks the same even after adding that key variable

Answer (score 0):

`foreach ($values as &$value)`